# Margin 0 auto not centering in small screens issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show the image inside the div with `margin 0 auto` property.Now the problem that i am facing is that in big screens image is coming fine while in small screens it is it moving more to right with leaving space in the left .I have no idea why is this happening..

Here is the HTML..

```
 <div id="headerbodyimage" class="headerbody-wrapper">

 </div>
```

and Here is the css..

```
.headerbody-wrapper {
background: url("../images/banner.jpg");
float: left;
margin-top: 77px;
height: 242px;
position: inherit;
width: 100%;
z-index: 60001; }
```

So my question is how to center this div image in all the browsers.
Please help me.

Comment: Adjust width to not 100%, if you have 100% width then it is centered already since the width is 100%. Also kill the float left. Match your css class to your html. Also kill position absolute

Comment: I'm surprised it's working on any screen resolution/size. Get rid of the floating, absolute positioning and width (100%). Also, as mentioned below, your class name is not matching the CSS selector.

Comment: Also, your CSS rule does not have the same name as your element class anyway

Comment: Your margin also won't work while you have `position: absolute;`

Comment: headerbody-wrapper  ->  .header-wrapper

Comment: @user3699193 well your CSS rule is .header-wrapper but the element class is headerbody-wrapper, unless you've posted it wrong on here how is it even using any of the CSS on the element

Comment: This should be enough, just add the correct width: `.headerbody-wrapper { background: url("../images/call_biling_banner.jpg"); margin: 77px auto 0 auto; height: 242px; position: relative; z-index: 60001; }`

Comment: @MelanciaUK My full image width is 1600px while the contents of the image is in 960 px;So to show this image in all the size screens

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem is in background-position

so your CSS must be

```
.header-wrapper {
background: url("../images/header_bg.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
float: left;
height: 77px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
z-index: 60001; }
```

Comment: It seems you copied the css from the question and pasted here

Comment: @Huangism He added some properties to the second line.

Comment: @Huangism Yes, but I add some changes in background property. I really not understand why I have downvoted

Comment: @user3657431 I did not downvote but your answer does not solve the issue of the div not centering with `margin: 0 auto` but now it seems confusing as to what is not centering or what OP wants to center

Comment: You got downvoted because your proposed solution doesn't solve the problem as asked by the OP.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Did you tried it? I have perfectly centered image. Maybe he want to center div. If so he needs to add max-width: to the div.

Comment: The question was how to center a div horizontally using margin 0 auto. By playing with the background position you can surely find a centering point, but that's not an answer for the question as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Best case is if your element with a margin 0 has a fixed width (no percentage). and position absolute and margin is not working. so i removed position absolute. 
If your width of the div is 100% the margin around can't center it because it's always 100%. and there is no space for centering.

this works.

```
.header-wrapper {
    background: url("../images/header_bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 77px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}
```

and if you need to make your div larger on bigger screens. you can add a media query. see the example below... or you gonna work with wrappers who define the width of the element.

```
@media all and (min-width: 699px) {
 .header-wrapper {
        background: url("../images/header_bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        height: 77px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 700px; /* bigger here */
    }
}
```

Comment: if i am removing float:left ,my design is collapsing

Comment: Please create a fiddle with your markup, so we can help you better.
http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: My full image width is 1600px while the contents of the image is in 960 px;So to show this image in all the size screens

Comment: I want to show the image with width of 960px at the center of the screen